# Does Elixir have a `Kernel.delete_in` equivalent?

Tags: elixir

Elixir's [`Kernel.put_in`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#put_in/2) is great for adding or updating a value deep in a nested structure.  It does not, however, support deleting the value, and I don't see a `delete_in` anywhere.

Does `delete_in`, `pop_in`, or some equivalent exist?  Something like

```
def delete_in(data, keys) do
    put_in(data, keys, :magic_value_that_deletes_the_final_key)
end
```

Without it, adding- and updating- functions look like nice pipelines, but deleting or popping functions look less tidy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [`Kernel.pop_in/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#pop_in/1) and [`Kernel.pop_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#pop_in/2) exist, which return both the deleted value and the data value without the key/path we just deleted.

```
iex(1)> data = %{1 => %{2 => %{3 => 4, 5 => 6}}}
%{1 => %{2 => %{3 => 4, 5 => 6}}}
iex(2)> pop_in(data, [1, 2, 5])
{6, %{1 => %{2 => %{3 => 4}}}}
iex(3)> pop_in(data[1][2][5])
{6, %{1 => %{2 => %{3 => 4}}}}
```

To get only the data without the popped value you can use pattern matching or `|> elem(1)`:

```
iex(4)> pop_in(data, [1, 2, 5]) |> elem(1)
%{1 => %{2 => %{3 => 4}}}
iex(5)> pop_in(data[1][2][5]) |> elem(1)
%{1 => %{2 => %{3 => 4}}}
```

Comment: Hilarious that I didn't notice that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**!  [`Kernel.get_and_update_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#get_and_update_in/3) takes a function as the third argument that, per the docs,

> must return a two-element tuple: the “get” value (the retrieved value,
>   which can be operated on before being returned) and the new value to be
>   stored under key. **The fun may also return :pop**, implying the current 
>   value shall be removed from the structure and returned.

So `delete_in` could be written as

```
def delete_in(data, keys) do
  {_val, data} = get_and_update_in(data, keys, fn key -> :pop end)
  data
end
```

or one could use `get_and_update_in/3` in a pipeline directly, like

```
data
|> get_and_update(keys, fn key -> :pop end)
|> elem(1)
```